# MYSQL How to cancel or void WHERE clause within WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

What would be the best value for selecting all rows(canceling WHERE clause)?

```
  <select id="ddlSelect">
    <option value = ???? > -- SELECT ALL -- </option>
    <option value = "1" > 1 </option>
    <option value = "2" > 2 </option>
  </select>
```

Select query

```
"SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME WHERE EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID = " + ddlSelect.Value;
```

For `-- SELECT ALL --` I tried `1 OR 1 =1`. It works fine but isn't there better way?

Comment: view my posted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563543/mysql-how-to-cancle-or-void-where-clause-within-where-clause/19563640#19563640

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="ddlSelect">
  <option value = "all" > -- SELECT ALL -- </option>
  <option value = "1" > 1 </option>
  <option value = "2" > 2 </option>
</select>
```

And in your **.net** code

```
String strQuery = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM table_name";

if(ddlSelect.Value != "all") {
   strQuery += " WHERE EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID = " + ddlSelect.Value;
}
```

Sorry i am't familiar on .net

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = '';
if($('#ddlSelect').val() > 0)
     query  = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME from table_name WHERE EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID = " + $('#ddlSelect').val() ;
else
     query  = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME from table_name";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about your answer.